# TypoScript : make transversal MySQL query without use of `pidInList` option

Tags: database, typo3, typoscript

As [it's mentioned on TYPO3 wiki](http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Functions/Select/Index.html), we could make a query with TypoScript :

```
page.60 = CONTENT
page.60 {
   table = tt_content
   select {
       pidInList = 73
       where = header != ###whatever###
       orderBy = ###sortfield###
       markers {
         whatever.data = GP:first
         sortfield.value = sor
         sortfield.wrap = |ting
       }
   }
}
```

What is inconvenient for me, it's parameter pidInList. Even when we didn't use it, the script substitute *current page id* with pid in the query. Is there a way to make it simpliler, for example, to realize such simple query :

```
select title from pages where uid=100;
```

What be the simpliest TypoScript equivalent ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your example:

```
SELECT title FROM pages WHERE uid=100;
```

the simplest TypoScript equivalent is:

```
page.60 = RECORDS
page.60 {
    tables = pages
    source = 100
    dontCheckPid  = 1
    conf.pages = TEXT
    conf.pages.field = title
    }
```

Note that the `source` parameter is mandatory. For more flexible queries I'd recommend writing a quick [userFunc](http://www.typo3wizard.com/en/snippets/common-problems-and-solutions/simple-userfunc.html).

Comment: Works perfectly, suite my needs. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know `pidInList` is required. The workaround is to set it to "0" and use the `recursive` attribute.

```
page.60 = CONTENT
page.60 {
   table = tt_content
   select {
       pidInList = 0
       recursive = 99
       where = header != ###whatever###
       orderBy = ###sortfield###
       markers {
         whatever.data = GP:first
         sortfield.value = sor
         sortfield.wrap = |ting
       }
   }
}
```

**NOTE**:
If you are worried about the performance impact and you are selecting records purely by their UIDs, consider using the `RECORDS` object instead.

Comment: Thanks ! As I understand, such query will generate multiple subqueries, what will potentially generate server overcharge, especially on complex installations ?

Comment: I don't know how TYPO3 performs such querries. It might have no noticable impact. It might gather all the possible page UIDs and then perform the query containing `pid IN(list of page UIDs)`. Sure there would always be some extra querries but the performance impact would be negligible.

Comment: I've just checked and it seems to work the way I mentioned so that in the final query `pidInList` is simply replaced with the list of all possible pages in the tree.

Comment: Logically, we should get from somewhere this "list of all possible pages in the tree", so there is still a risk of performance overload due to multiplies subqueries. So I prefer to use RECORDS, where we could ignore the pid parameter.

Comment: Yes, `RECORDS` object is better if you search only by UID. Yes, `select` with the `recursive` attribute is less effective. However, I wouldn't talk about "**overload**" unless you can really experience it. Firstly, those several extra querries that it has to perform are quite simple. Secondly, the query results are probably cached. I don't have any performance test data from a large website but my guess is that the extra load would be negligible. After all, if you are building a large website, you can do the comparison and share the results. ;-)

Comment: Do You know how I could measure the time of generation of single TS object and the number of queries, which were fired ? You could propose such methods here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10534263/how-to-benchmark-single-typosript-object-generation Thanks !