# How to benchmark single TypoSript Object generation?

Tags: performance, benchmarking, typo3, typoscript

I would like to benchmark single TypoScript object generation to control the performance, is it possible, probably, with some stdWrap methods ?

Example of TS objects, which I would like to benchmark :

**Test 1**

```
  page.10 = RECORDS
    page.10 {
        tables = pages
        source = 1
        dontCheckPid  = 1
        conf.pages = TEXT
        conf.pages.field = title
    }
```

**Test 2**

```
page.20 = CONTENT
page.20 {
   table = tt_content
   select {
       pidInList = 0
       recursive = 99
       where = uid = 1
   }
}
```

I need each object generation time and quantity of fired queries.

Comment: Thumbs up for taking up my challenge! :-) I wouldn't go as far as to trying to track generation of each object. I think it would be enough if on one particular page you tracked number of MySQL querries and page generation time using once Test 1 case and once Test 2 case.

Comment: Thanks, I've found `typo3profiler` extension, it gives statistics You've described. I still would like more clean test with different benchmark possibilities. If there is no alternatives, I've some ideas about how to implement it.

Comment: Also check the admin panel. It has nice TS debug options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it could be done via Extension. I guess there is a possibility to hook in (or xclass) the Database Layer (like DBAL does). In your extension you could then just test the different TypoScript setups via `$this->cObj->cObjGetSingle($this->conf['test1'],$this->conf['test1.'],'test1');`

Perhaps have a look at t3lib_timeTrack, may be it is enough what is tracked there. But AFAIK everything which is tracked is available via Admin-Panel (check all checkboxes).

Comment: I think, it's possible to do in COA, where first and last element - time renderers, and the middle one - tested Object.